# Query with primary key obtained from primary keys of underlying tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access which I'd like to substitute with a query which gathers data from the table and other new tables. The table is used by many queries which look to a primary key (autonumber) in the table, so the new query must have a primary key which is a unique combination of the primary keys of the tables used by the query. What can I do?

--EDIT--

Solution found: Since I want to "merge" tables with a query, and since the pk is an autonumber, I can define the new pk (of the query) by "expanding the numbering": I multiply both pkeys by 2 (because I have two tables) and add or subtract 1 to one of the two (or 1 for the first table and 2 for the second, and so on).
For example:
PK1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6
PK2 = 1,3,4,5,8,9,10 (some records may have been deleted, so the number is skipped)

new PK = (2*PK1, (2*PK2 + 1)) = (2,4,6,8,10,12),(3,7,9,11,17,19,21)
as you can see they will never overlap (no new value of PK2 can be obtained from any value of PK1, because of the "+1") because math says they belong to different vector spaces.

Hope it may help somebody

Answer (score 0):

Use composite key (Multiple-field primary key)

Comment: I can't touch existing queries, they want an autonumber field as a primary key